# Trouble setting up XDebug with MAMP Pro 1.9.2 & MacGDBp v1.3.1

Tags: configuration, ide, xdebug, mamp

I installed the XDebug package at MAMP/bin/php5.2/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613
I put the following into my php.ini file:

```
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.2/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-0060613/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_host = localhost
xdebug.remote_port = 9999
```

I disabled the zend optimizer. 
I set the proper port # in MacGDBp.
I do get a proper stack trace from the command line. 
What I'd like to do, though, is load a page in Firefox and debug with MacGDBp. 
Shouldn't MacGDBp be reading and parsing whatever's coming though the specified port? 
Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are a bit unspecific about your concrete setup but there seem to be few things odd with your settings.

I am not using mac and I don't know MacGDBp ... but MacGDBp suggests that it uses the old GDP-protocol. Though XDebug 2 uses by default the new DBG protocol.

You should make that explicit by setting 'xdebug.remote_handler' to your preferred protocol. In my case as I use the new protocol i feed it 'dpgp.

Here you find some information: http://www.xdebug.org/docs/remote

Also it could be that your firewall is blocking the port.

Maybe that'll do it, otherwise tell us more about the symptoms.

Best

Raffael

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem.

What I did was:

- install the [xdebug-toggler plugin for Safari](https://github.com/benmatselby/xdebug-toggler)
- load the page I was testing
- enable the plugin
- reload the page

And suddenly it worked.